# Installing multiple copies of library on Unix

Tags: c++, unix, sfml

So suppose I have installed the SFML 1.6 C++ library from the Ubuntu repositories. Then I have header files in /usr/include/SFML, library files in /usr/lib etc.

Now I have also downloaded a recent source tarball and built and installed SFML 2.0 into /usr/local.

So by default, if I #include , it gets the SFML 2.0 copy from /usr/local/include. Similarly, it links to libraries from /usr/local/lib.

My question is, how can I tell the compiler/linker to get the files from /usr/include and /usr/lib? I tried
g++ -I/usr/include
but it didn't work. Is this possible at all? Or should I just keep the 'home built' copy in a non system location?

Comment: `/usr/local` is generally searched in preference to the other directories by GCC and in order to change this you probably have to hack the *spec file*, which is not advised.  If you don't want SFML 2.0 to be used then remove it and all will be well.  If you still want to keep it about, then install it into something like `/usr/local/sfml2` where g++ won't find it unless you tell it about it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the ldconfig command. I guess running it in the destination folder of the newer version of the library should do the trick.